# Color setting in OBIEE 12c for an attribute

Tags: oracle, obiee

How do I customize the colors for an attribute in OOBE 12c?

Registration date colors in reports are counted from today's date:

red for more than 30 days

yellow 14-30

green 7-14

no color less than

Attribute name is "registration_date".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting. You create conditions for those values on your column and the rendering will take those into account

https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/obips/pivot_cross_conditionnal_formating

Comment: This option is not very suitable. Since there are a lot of options for values. I rather need something like this:
Today - registration date> 7 days (red option)
In addition, the date is presented as 31-12-2000 00:00:00

Comment: So? Make a column that represents our logic and colour "Column A" based on the "Condition Column". It's simple and has been done thousands of times.